# onActivityResult() has Intent data as null after an Activity has finished

Tags: android

Hi there I am calling an startActivityForResult() and trying to process the result in the onAcvityResult() method. However, the Intent data is null and result is RESULT_CANCELED. I am not sure why though.

I am creating activity with:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Class.class),LIST_RESULT);
```

then in the Activity class

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent data = new Intent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putParcelable("name", la);
    data.putExtras(bundle);

    if (getParent() == null) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    } else {
        getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    }

    //finish();
}
```

finish() has no effect. In fact I get warning in LogCat that duplicate finish request HistoryRecord

And I am processing the result in:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode) {
    case(LIST_RESULT):
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            previousList = data.getExtras();
        }
    break;
    }

}
```

data is null and the resultCode is the Action.RESULT_CANCELED.

Any ideas why I am not getting any through? Is something changing it in between me setting it and reading it? The mParent is also null in the activity that returns result.

Alex

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Alex,

I think you want to remove the called to `finish()` in your `onBackPressed()` method, and replace it with the call to `super.onBackPressed()`.  I believe the call to `super.onBackPressed()` is calling finish and you are never getting a chance to call `setResult()`.

Try...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent data = new Intent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putParcelable("name", la);
    data.putExtras(bundle);

    if (getParent() == null) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    } else {
        getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Worked yea! Interestingly, I was able to set result code but intent was returning null still. after changing super call it's fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the proposed solution and the original question example.  In my case , the same error above was reusing the same requestCode value.

Pay attention to your requestCode on using startActivityForResult, each Activity call should have a different requestCode.

If you reuse or don’t pay attention to your requestCode to be unique for each Activity call you will get the following error message:

“onActivityResult() has Intent data as null after an Activity has finished” or ”Failure delivering result ResultInfo”.

Use variable definition for each startActivityForResult,to ensure clarity.  ex.

public static final int INITIATIVE_REQUEST = 11

```
      Use a unique number for each of startActivityForResult.
```

Again repeating the same requestCode on multiple Activities will result on the above message.